# How to split or separate Serialize Form Data in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

When I'm submit my modal form using JQuery. I receive the form data using `serialize()` method and I'm send it to my controller method using AJAX. But in my controller i want access single value from this data but i can't un-serialize this data. How can i do this ??

Here is my JQuery Part.

```
  $('#btnSave').on('click',function(){
     var data = $('#form').serialize();
     $.ajax({
       url:"{{route('product.update')}}",
       method:'post',
       data:{data:data,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
       success:function(data)
       {
         console.log(data);
        
       }
     });
```

Here is my Controller Method.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  $data=$request->all();
  $title=$data['title']
    return $title;

}
```

Here is my output.

> Object { data: "product_id=1&title=Prof.&description=Amet%20rem%20autem%20doloremque%20expedita%20consequatur%20quos.%20Dolore%20veritatis%20in%20expedita%20consequatur%20porro.%20Quaerat%20voluptate%20et%20non%20quia.%20Possimus%20recusandae%20voluptates%20sequi.&price=93040", _token: "trqOM0WJDUY8rf00K75S1O6AAOn84r6aG3hQ1Jhp" }

Comment: just use  `$title=$request->title` the $request is an Object not an array

Comment: _$title=$request->title_ tried. but show nothing.

Comment: `dd($request)` what do you see?

Comment: now halt the modal the model and show nothing.

Comment: sorry, to clarify, what do you see in your network tab of your document inspector?

Answer (score 2):

You're nesting your parameters, try this

```
$('#btnSave').on('click',function(){
  var data = $('#form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url:"{{route('product.update')}}",
    method:'post',
    data:data+'&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
    success:function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Didn't even notice that You are right! Upvoted over my answer

Answer (score 0):

The $request is an object not an array

**js**

```
success:function(msg){
console.log(msg);
}
```

just to make sure that it is not trying to pass the data var that is sent to the controller

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  $title=$request->title;
  return $title;
}
```